# How to calculate mid point vertices?

Tags: geometry, vertices

I have a set of vertices to draw a circle, but I want to draw a high-res circle by drawing twice the number of vertices, I cant just increase the number of vertices what I need is to calculate the mid points from the supplied vertices, if that makes sense
[image]

So from that image how can I calculate the points A, B, C, ...  given the points V0, V1, V2, ... and the center point of the circle ?
Please note that I cant just calculate the mid-points by rotating the vertices they need to be calculated using their position

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The center of the circle can be determined by making a perpendicular line to two neighboring "sides", and intersecting them.

If there are an even number of vertices, just pick two which are opposite to each other, and "avarage them" - calculate the midpoint.

Then, you can just rotate all the vertices to either way by 180°/No.vertices around this center, so you get the ones you are looking for. Of course, you should keep the existing ones too.

Comment: Help for coordinate rotation: http://www.oocities.org/davidvwilliamson/rotpoint.jpg

To have (x,y) be rotateable around the origo, subtract the polygon's center from the vertexes coordinates first,rotate it using the formula in the image, and finally add "back" the center.